# React Native - Ref seems to be undefined

Tags: react-native

can somebody please help me with "ref" in this code. In the last "view" component, it seems that "this.multiSelect" is undefined. I dont understand why and where do I make mistake. Thas it have something with context or?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MultiSelect from 'react-native-multiple-select';

export default class MultiSelectComponent extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedItems : []
    };

    this.items = [{
      id: '92iijs7yta',
      name: 'Ondo',
    }, {
      id: 'suudydjsjd',
      name: 'Abuja',
    }];
  }

  onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MultiSelect
            hideTags
            items={this.items}
            uniqueKey="id"
            ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component; }}
            onSelectedItemsChange = {this.onSelectedItemsChange}
            selectedItems={selectedItems}
            selectText="Pick Items"
            searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
            submitButtonText="Submit"
        />
        <View>
            {this.multiselect
            ? 
            this.multiselect.getSelectedItemsExt(selectedItems)
            :
            null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `this` in `this.multiselect`

Comment: Where have you defined `this.multiselect` ?

Comment: I have just copied this code frome here: 
https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select

The difference is that I have constructor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, the error is maybe there : 
you are using this.multiselect and declaring

```
ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component; }}
```

so maybe with thi :

```
ref={(component) => { this.multiselect = component; }}
```

Comment: Ohh lords, how blind I was :) Thank you so much, after 2 days and trying all combinations with state and props... it was just typo :D

Comment: Typos are sooo painful sometimes :D